# My web site has ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID when running on mobile client

Tags: .net, ssl, iis, web-hosting, windows-server

I run website with `.Net 5` on `Windows Server 2019` and `IIS 10` webserver and get SSL with `win-acme`.
in windows client browser don't have any problem. but when i tested from android browser such as `Samsung Internet Browser` or `Chrome` give `ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` error.

[image]

error when using `Chrome` on mobile
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Chrome will return this error if the certificate is not a trusted ca certificate. you can try to keep going to the website by clicking the advance button. I think you could just ignore this issue until you need to expose the website to public and use a public CA certificate for this website.

Of course, you could add the self-signed cerificate to chrome ca store:

https://superuser.com/questions/1083766/how-do-i-deal-with-neterr-cert-authority-invalid-in-chrome